# Ryanair's API limit

Tags: api, limit, quota

I started a project using Ryanair's web API but sometimes I get the following error message:

```
{
    "fault": {
        "faultstring": "Rate limit quota violation. Quota limit  exceeded. Identifier : _default",
        "detail": {
            "errorcode": "policies.ratelimit.QuotaViolation"
        }
    }
}
```

I immediatly searched for a usage limit in the developers website and in internet and I found I have a limit of 200 requests per minute, however I make one every 15 seconds. Does anyone know the problem? What should I do beside contacting the (lacking) support?

Comment: Just a thought: Are you authenticating with their API or are you using a public one? Perhaps the 200 limit is for authorized requests?

Comment: I have an approved application which I'm using with my own Consumer Key.

Comment: I also started to experience same problem around the end of April. Seams like there is no possible answer anywhere - I've reached Ryanair support, but except general information about 200 request per minute, there is no other info (and I send far less request, with 5 secs delay between them).

Comment: Thank you for the response, I reached them too and if I'll get any response I let you know.

Comment: Hello @Vexorei. Do you have any updates about this issue? I have the same trouble from time to time(

Comment: Hi @Luchnik and no, I haven't find any solution yet..